# Count occurrences between two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, count

So, lets say I have these two arrays:

`const arr1 = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "mango", "cherry"]`

`const arr2 = ["apple", "mango"]`

How to get the number of occurrences in arr1 from arr2. All the strings in both arrays will be unique and there won't be duplicates. Obviously, the result in this concrete case is 2.

What I have tried:

```js
const arr1 = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "mango", "cherry"]

const arr2 = ["apple", "mango"]


let count = 0
arr2.forEach(i =>
  arr1.includes(i) ? count++ : count );
  console.log(count);
```

The problem is I have to use this in few cases and the `count` variable is always changing, depending on what you click and you cannot rely on its value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Extract to a function that returns the count?

Comment: The problem you have is not visible from the code you have given. Please demonstrate the issue with code.

Comment: @trincot I assume OP uses something like `if (count > 2)` in one place and `if (count < 4)` in another but the counts are of different pairs of arrays.

Comment: `arr2.filter(fruit => arr1.includes(fruit)).length` o.O

Comment: @Andreas I'd extract that to a function, as well, assuming it's used several times as OP suggests their code is.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, it's just a _"why so complicated?"_

Comment: @Andreas eh, in either case the way the question is worded, it seems like this code is being copy/pasted *including* the variable. Extracting to a function is the first step, then the function can be improved, if needed.

Comment: @VLAZ your assumption is right, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is what you are looking for:

```
const arr1 = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "mango", "cherry"];
const arr2 = ["apple", "mango"];

// count items
const count = arr1.filter(i => arr2.includes(i)).length;

console.log(count) // displays 2
```